# How can I access focal length of active camera, render resolution using animation nodes most directly?

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like to use animation nodes to create edge line meshes for fast edge line rendering-- meshes slightly displaced along their normals, with only backfaces rendered.  To create an edge line that's a single pixel wide, the world-space displacement needs to depend on the camera FoV (focal length + sensor size) as well as the rendering dimensions.

I would like to use animation nodes to do this, as it would simplify the creation of objects and should allow for easy reuse between projects.  I have just started learning animation nodes.

How can I most easily get these numbers into my node trees?  I've tried using object attribute input with a copied data path on my active camera object, but get an "attribute not found".  A copied data path to an expression node for render resolution likewise gives me "name is not defined."  Drivers seem to not be working on float input nodes in animation nodes.  I can create drivers on the positions of empties and access their positions in my node trees, but I'm wondering if there is a more direct way to access this for animation nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to directly access the current Scene's properties in Animations nodes but you can circumvent that with custom properties
.

Add 2 custom properties to your camera and drive them using your resolution. Example with the resolution X :

[image]

Now you can access theses properties in AN using an "Attribute Input" node.

Note : To access the "Camera" part of the Camera "Object", the path is `obj.data`

So : the focal lens is accessed with `data.lens`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  Much more direct than using object transforms to store the information.